# VLOOKUP and fill all cells in a date range

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have two sheets:

-**booking** gets data from a form (`car nr`, `registration nr`, `car model`, `starting date` and `return date`). Values for `registration nr` and `car model` are coming from dispo by a vlookup)
- **dispo** is actually only a calendar with all the dates day by day on the first line and in the first four columns: `car nr`, `registration nr`, `car model` and the date of `today`.

My program has to register the data from the form into "booking" (that works) then from this find the cell in "dispo" corresponding to the `starting date` and `car nr` and put a "x" in it (well actually I want to have an "x" in all cells between `starting date` and `return date)`.

For now, `car nr` is fixed to 1. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmdajout_Click()

Dim dispo As Worksheet
Dim booking As Worksheet
Dim db As Range
Dim ligne As Integer
Dim l As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim maxc As Long
Dim maxl As Long

Set dispo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dispo")
Set booking = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("booking")
Set db = dispo.Range("A2:C35")

vehicule = 1

' find the first empty row
If Sheets("booking").Range("A2").Value = "" Then
ligne = 2
Else:
ligne = Sheets("booking").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
End If

' copy the data from the form to "booking" and get by vlookup the missing data
booking.Range("A" & ligne).Value = vehicule
imma = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(booking.Range("A" & ligne), db, 2, False)
booking.Range("B" & ligne).Value = imma
model = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(booking.Range("A" & ligne), db, 3, False)
booking.Range("C" & ligne).Value = model
booking.Range("D" & ligne).Value = Format(txtdepart, "short date")
booking.Range("E" & ligne).Value = Format(txtfin, "short date")
booking.Range("F" & ligne).Value = txtclient
booking.Range("G" & ligne).Value = txtlocation
Unload Me

' book the date in the calendar "dispo"
dispo.Select
maxc = dispo.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
maxl = dispo.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For c = 5 To maxc
If dispo.Cells(1, c).Value = txtdepart Then 'it's here that i don't understant ... if i write = "05-01-2013" it finds it, but if i write = txtdepart (wich is where in the form i entered the date), it doesnt find
    For l = 2 To maxl
        If dispo.Range("A" & l).Value = vehicule Then 'same proble here ... it finds if i enter ="1" but not if i write = vehicule
        dispo.Cells(l, c).Value = "x"
        Else:
        End If
    Next l
Else:
End If
Next c
End Sub
```

1. Anyone to help me with my problem ?
2. Can anyone also give me the code for it to put an "x" in all the cells between `starting date` and `return date`?

Comment: Ce site est en anglais uniquement - il va falloir traduire la question si tu veux obtenir des reponses.

Comment: I hope me commenting in English doesn't cause offence; your English is no doubt better than my French. Following http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/, I'd suggest either redrafting your question in English (broken English is better than none), or finding a French-speaking forum that may be able to help.

Comment: (if anyone can translate the above to French, feel free)

Comment: Pero qué le pasa a este? Habla un andaluz muy raro LOL

Comment: @varocarbas I've never been to Andalusia, so I wouldn't know. I do know how to use Google Translate though. :)

Comment: @AdrianWragg go there is a nice place; I am not from Andalusia, better ask Kespell for further information :)

Comment: ok sorry for that, wrote it in english :)

Comment: @Kespell Much easier to understand. Have prodded a friend of mine who knows his way around VBA better than I do.

Comment: This is the right way, Kespell; actually, it is not too difficult(lots of online translators). This is an English-speaking network and thus you have to speak in English (otherwise you should look for french-speaking ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making conditions between different types/values (which, logically, do not hold):
`dispo.Cells(1, c).Value = txtdepart` would work if both variables have the same type (and content), that is, string = string or date = date. Apparently you are expecting dates an thus you can use the following code to make completely sure:

```
If Format(CDate(dispo.Cells(1, c).Value), "dd-MM-yyyy") = Format(CDate(txtdepart), "dd-MM-yyyy") Then
```

Equivalent problem for

```
If dispo.Range("A" & l).Value = vehicule Then
```

Both members have to be identical. Above you are writing `vehicule = 1` and thus this condition wlll only verify if `dispo.Range("A" & l).Value` equals 1.

No idea what you want to write in the `"x"` part.

Comment: ok, I'm going to look at it to see if i can fix it this way :) For the "x", i just want for now the program to put a x in the cells when the car is rented ... later on I'll try to merge the cells betwenn starting date and return date and write the name of the driver + destination :)

Comment: @Kespell Feel free to ask anything else you need. See? it is not so difficult to write in English (much less with online translators). If you want to use this site, you have to accept its rules.

Comment: to be honest i've been checking so many pages in french or english to get help i didnt pay attention if this one was english or french eheh my bad. And it's not at all a problem for me to write in english as I'm not living in France and not using french at all for work :)

Comment: @Kespell if you want to put an "x" and the right cell is dispo.Cells(l, c), your code is fine. Perhaps the "x"s are not being written because the conditions are wrong and the code does not reach the dispo.Cells(l, c).Value = "x" part. Make sure that the conditions are right (as suggested) and see if the "x"s start to be written.

Comment: @Kespell no problem at all. Some people comes here and start to talk in their language because they don't think that should adapt themselves to the rules of this site. If you just made an error, there is no problem at all (much less when you corrected it as soon as you could).

Comment: kk it works perfectly now with your solution :) will work alone to make it put x in all cells between starting and ending date. I may come back to bug you if i can't find if it's ok for you !! I like to find things myself tbh eheh only coming here if i REALLY can't find alone :)

Comment: @Kespell happy to hear that. If you think that this answer has solved your problem, please, click on the tick sign you can see on the left hand side :)